# Transpile specific `node_modules` package with rollup and babel

Tags: babeljs, rollupjs

I'm using rollup and would like to babel transpile a single `node_modules` package to ES5 (more precisely: to work with IE11).

With the following set-up it transpiles some of the code — classes → functions for example — but it doesn't transpile `const` to `var`'s:

#### rollup.config.js:

```js
import resolve from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve';
import commonjs from '@rollup/plugin-commonjs';
import babel from '@rollup/plugin-babel';

export default {
  input: 'src/index.js',
  output: {
    file: 'dist/bundle.js',
    format: 'umd',
  },
  plugins: [
    resolve(),
    commonjs(),
    babel({
      babelHelpers: 'bundled', 
      exclude: 'node_modules\/(?!(roughjs)\/).*', // ← Here I try to ES5 transpile roughjs which lives in `node_modules/roughjs/bundled/rough.esm.js`
    }),
  ],
};
```

#### .babelrc

```js
{
  "presets": [["@babel/env", { "modules": false }]]
}
```

#### package.json:

```json
// ...
"browserslist": "> 0.5%, IE 11, not dead",
// ...
```

My question is: how do I successfully transpile a single or multiple `node_modules` packages (given above example, if of help)?

Comment: Does it work if you rename `.babelrc` to `babel.config.json`?

Comment: @loganfsmyth no change unfortunately. Is `.babelrc` inferior?

Comment: `.babelrc` only affects your own package files, so it would never work for `node_modules`, so for this it is definitely required.

Comment: @Ive Did you find a solution?

Comment: You should be able to apply Babel explicitly to a package in `node_modules`, it can be done in Webpack but I don't know how to do it with rollupjs

Comment: @tjespe I'll pick this up again soon and report back then.

Comment: @AluanHaddad yeah - it's a rollup app...

Comment: @tjespe I did spent some more time on it and couldn't get it to work with above set up using `babel.config.json` (which should work as far as I can see). I ended up manually transpiling the ES6 library in question to ES5 and import it from a src folder. Certainly not optimal but workable...

Comment: @Ive for me it suddenly worked when setting plugins to be `resolve(), typescript({ typescript: require("ttypescript"), declaration: true, tsconfig: "./tsconfig.json", }), json(), commonjs({ include: /node_modules/, }), babel({ plugins: ["macros"], extensions: [".js", ".ts", ".jsx", ".tsx"], presets: ["@babel/react", "@babel/typescript"], })` in that order. I guess that transpiles all packages, though, so it's not really an answer to this question. I'm not really sure what made it work either.